# Feature-First Driven Structure in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, clean-architecture

I have a question about feature-first structure. In this architecture, if we have shared roseources - models, repositories and etc, we can define them inside `shared`, `common` or other folders like these. But I have question from other aspect.

Assume instagram, we have features like - stories and posts from other people in the home page (same page). I think we should divide it to two different features because they are independent. But how we should join them and in which folder? If we create new feature like "home" it is not okay because it should not depend on other features. So I think that we should create shared/presentation/pages/home like feature to join them in one place? am I right?

I think we don't have other way.

I have two features - posts and users and shared folder, shared contains shared models and entities for this case. But I don't know that how can I connect two features - `posts` and `users` in one page?

[image: FEATURE-FIRST STRUCTURE]

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this? At the beginning I also liked the modularity of the feature-first approach. So clean, so easy to read. A part from the difficult initial phase where you need to think about all the features of the app (rarely the case for a new app), the more you develop you app with it, the more problems arise. Your problem is the first one. Then again, if I have the auth feature, then I also need to create subfeatures for the user_repo and maybe the profile_repo... So the folder structure isn't anymore that clean.

Comment: Is there a sort of hybrid approach to this? The layer-first approach is easier to setup, but then if you want to split the layers in different packages, each package would be dependent on every other package. Presentation would need the data and domain folder, maybe even the utils and constants from the main project package, for example. Did someone figure this out?

Comment: Why should features not depend on other features?